# Timestamp doesn't add up together with old files time in kibana 4

Tags: elasticsearch, timestamp, logstash, kibana

I've started reading in old files using logstash. They get read as they should although the automatic timestamp in kibana 4 doesn't add up together with the actual time for the different events in the logs.

The timestamp is the time it indexed the event but I want it to show the time the event actually happened which you can locate in the source and it says "22/Jun/2015 :05:35:37"

Is there a setting you need to do in the logstash configuration to get Kibana 4 to get the time right?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Logstash's date filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html) to parse the timestamp in each log message and populate the `@timestamp` field, which is what Kibana uses. If you don't do this Logstash will (as you've noticed) default to using the current time.

With the date format you have,

```
filter {
  date {
    match => ["timestamp", "dd/MMM/YYYY :HH:mm:ss"]
  }
}
```

should work, assuming you've extracted the timestamp to the `timestamp` field (which is temporary and deleted when we've successfully parsed it).

Comment: I really don't know what I'm missing. I've been debugging Logstash and all the fields checks out as they should. The @timestamp field gets populated with the information from my custom filer "mytimestamp". It's still populated with the same information in Elasticsearch. Something happens in Kibana 4 that makes that change.